# How to customize serializing of java object

Tags: java, jackson, fasterxml

How to serialize that object. But only with fields of object anotherObject  but without "anotherObject" key in json

```java
class A{
   int some = 1;
   B anotherObject = new B();
}

class B{
    int someB = 2;
}
```

I need as serializing result next JSON

```js
{
    "A":{
       some: 1,
       anotherSome: 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on anotherObject vs anotherSome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@JsonUnwrapped` annotation.

```
class A {
    @JsonProperty
    int some = 1;

    @JsonUnwrapped
    B anotherObject = new B();
}

class B {
    @JsonProperty
    int someB = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to your class a method

```
int getAnotherSome() {
  return anotherObject.someB
}
```

And annotate

```
@JsonIgnore
B anotherObject = new B();
```

And that should do a trick